# Joomla "People/Group matcher"?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms, joomla

I run a website for rowing club and was asked if there is a possibility to integrate a "people/group matching" functionality, such that people can organize themselves into rowing groups.

Specifically a "I look for a group" resp. "We look for a person"-like functionality. 
Searchability for custom fields would be a plus.

I have looked through the Joomla extensions page, however nothing stood out to me.

Does anyone of you happen to know a module/component (or web service) that provides such a service?

Kind regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

Sound like [Community builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/community-builder).

Comment: Thank you for your input! But they rather seem more like a dating-site component, than for groups? (I'll adjust the post to clarify)